# Post JSONArray to webservice and get the JSONObject Response in android

Tags: android, json

I am using the below code.In the below code "str" is JSONArray converted to string.I have to pass this "str" to the url

```
String serviceUrl = "http://172.16.10.64:8080/plugleadservices/rest/feedbackmanagement/feedbacknew";

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("feedbackjson", str) );
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serviceUrl);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));   
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonAr.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String json_str = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

My question is: **How to post JsonArray to the URL and get the JSON Object Response?**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is your Question ?

Comment: Use volley.. Refer this : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Posting JsonArray to the URL and getting the JSON Object Response.@ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: I am struck here from past 4 days.Any links would be appriaciated please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2 :**
Use Volley like this :

```
StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,urlJsonArry,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("", response.toString());

                    try 
                    {
                        // your response in JsonObject
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("feedbackjson",str);

            return params;

        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    // Adding request to request queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(activity).add(req);
```

Add this to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

or If you are using eclipse : download [volley.jar](http://api.androidhive.info/volley/volley.jar) here

**EDIT :**

Fix Imports like this :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Janki .Here in the above code we are passing JSONArray and the response is also JSONArray ?

Comment: Error  :  The constructor JsonArrayRequest(String, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){}, new Response.ErrorListener(){}) is undefined.

Comment: you are using Android Studio or Eclipse ?? If AS then you must Add the gradle dependency as i have suggested and Sync the project. If Eclipse then you need to Download the **Volley** library and add it to your `libs` folder.

Comment: I am using Eclipse

Comment: Fixed all imports, getting this error  :  The constructor JsonArrayRequest(String, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){}, new Response.ErrorListener(){}) is undefined.

Comment: can you please help me how to fix the above error ? @Janki

Comment: see my edit.. `StringRequest` will serve both purpose of using `JsonArray` and `JsonObject`. Try it once and let me know..!!

Comment: Thank you @Janki, i will definetly try this and will update you.

Comment: @ Janiki, Where to pass a method GET or POST ?I need to use POST method

Comment: Hi Naveen, If you're having problems with posting a JSONArray object, simply use a StringRequest. You can pass your JSONArray in a String representation.

Comment: i just used the above code but it is saying 405 error. @RuchiraRandana

Comment: I think you're calling a GET method when you need a POST. Or vice-versa.

Comment: How to change the method to POST from using above code ?

Comment: Guys please help me.

Comment: see my edit.. Just add `Request.Method.POST` while building the request.. i have changed here `StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,urlJsonArry,`. @Naveen

Comment: Thank you @jankigadhiya now it is 415 error even though i added Media type

Comment: return **String** from the server side.. If you are getting JsonArray then convert it to String using `toString()`. You are developing the server side too??

Comment: See my edit i have added header.. which will specify the content type..!!

Comment: Thank you so much.It helped me alot @jankigadhiya

Comment: Accepting the answer would be a favor if you found the solution..!!

Comment: i am not talking about up voting. clicking the **right** sign will make you accept the answer.. It is not green yet..!! :(

Comment: Accepted and it is green now :-)  @jankigadhiya

Comment: Thnxx.. Happy coding :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111396/discussion-between-naveen-and-janki-gadhiya).